# Flutter How to change container height based on the ListView's item height?

Tags: flutter, listview, layout

Hello I have a `Scaffold` wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView` and child is `Column`.
Inside Column; `Container`, `TabBar` and `TabBarView`.

First Container is just there for black space.

```
Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
```

The second widget of Column which mean `TabBar`:
(I know we can use it in AppBar but now it is what it is.)

```
 const TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.red,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "Tab1"),
                      Tab(text: "Tab2"),
                      Tab(text: "Tab3"),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Last Column widget is `TabBarView`. It wrapped by Container that has `300` `height`.

```
 Container(
                    height: 300, // here is problem
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: [
                        buildContainer(200, Colors.red, 2),
                        buildContainer(100, Colors.red, 2),
                        buildContainer(150, Colors.red, 3),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

and also this is `buildContainer` method;

```
buildContainer(double height, Color color, int count) => ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: height,
            color: color,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("my height ${height.toString()}"),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
```

[image]

Here is my question. I have 3 tabs and I have three `ListViewBuilder`.Each one has own child count. But all of them height limited to `300` because of their parent that is `Container`. I want to set `Tab's` height dynamicly with each `ListViewBuilder`'s item count.
How can I do that ? I accept **dynamic height  without child scrolling**. I mean, I can scroll whole page for reach the last child. In example, Instagram profile tab. If I have 30 photo, height is phone height. But I have 300 photo, it scrolling all the way down. But also, I don't want to understand pagenation for this one. I am not going to do Instagram. I just want to that, If I create 5 container, okey show me your max height. If I create 1 container, show me just that without scrolling.

Comment: still don't understand how does this work

Answer (score 1):

I added a dynamic height calculation depending on the number of objects in the ListView.builder. The formula is not perfect, you can add to it, but the point is to subtract the AppBar height and padding to get a clean screen area that the widget completely occupies.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: mainWidget(),
        );
      }
    
      Widget mainWidget() {
        AppBar appBar = AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 56, //You can manually set the AppBar height
          title: const Text("App bar"),
        );
        print(appBar.preferredSize); // Or you can save this value and use it later, it will not be fixed, but will depend on the screen size
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: appBar,
          body: HelpSO(color: Colors.red, count: 5),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class HelpSO extends StatelessWidget {
      late double height;
      Color color;
      int count;
    
      HelpSO({Key? key, required this.color, required this.count})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // height = (deviceHeight / itemCount) - padding (top + bottom) - appbar.prefferedSize.height / 2;
        height = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / count) - 16.0 - 56 / 2;
    
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // Subtract this value
                child: Container(
                  height: height,
                  color: color,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("My height ${height.toString()}"),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

[image: A picture that shows the use of 1, 3 and 5 widgets.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at flutter.I just come accros with this problem.
My solution was just wrap first or second(base on your logic) container with a **SingleChildScrollView**
Hope it will be helpful